# Java HttpPost to php page

Tags: java, php, post, http-post

I'm trying to call a `php` page from `Java` code, since i have a long string i have to use the `POST` method.
I tried the following code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri[0]);
if (params != null){
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
}
response = httpclient.execute(post);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
```

and also:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
URL obj = new URL(uri[0]);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
String urlParameters = "checkout=" + "dfdfdf" + "&location=" + "BOZEN";
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer responsei = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    responsei.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

Both get the php page, but when i call `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` they are empty array. If i use a HttGet i find the passed values in `$_GET`...
I guess the problem is setting the params in the right manner to the Post....but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I don't know why, but it works only when i remove the `www` from the `URL`...